# Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'checklists' between objects in different contexts

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm using Core Data for the offline storage of my iOS app, and I keep getting the following error:

> **Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'checklists' between objects in different contexts**

The problem is, I'm definitely using the same context to create the relationship. Below is the block of code that is triggering the issue:

```
 NSMutableSet *checklists = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *dict in array){
    Checklists *checklist = [self addChecklist:dict withContext:context];
    [checklists addObject:checklist];
    DLog(@"context: %@", checklist.managedObjectContext);
}

//Delete any lists that aren't from the server
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
Users *currentUser = (Users *)[self getUserWithId:[defaults objectForKey:@"user_id"] withContext:context];
DLog(@"context: %@", context);
currentUser.checklists = checklists;
```

The exception is thrown at the last line, `currentUser.checklists = checklists`. The log from the `context` is the same, and the objects are in the same thread. Has anyone run into this before?

Code for `addChecklist:withContext:`:

```
- (Checklists *) addChecklist:(NSDictionary *) dict withContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context{
    //Pull the list from the database and update
    Checklists *checklist = [self getChecklistWithId:dict[@"_id"] withContext:context];

    //If the list doesn't exist, add it to the database
    if(!checklist)
        checklist = (Checklists *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Checklists" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    //Update or create the list attributes
    checklist.checklist_id = dict[@"_id"] ? dict[@"_id"] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (arc4random() % 2000)];
    checklist.desc = dict[@"description"] == [NSNull null] ? nil : dict[@"description"];
    checklist.name = dict[@"name"] == [NSNull null] ? nil : dict[@"name"];
    checklist.published = dict[@"published"] == [NSNull null] ? 0 : dict[@"published"];
    checklist.created_at = dict[@"created_at"] == [NSNull null] ? nil : dict[@"created_at"];
    checklist.updated_at = dict[@"updated_at"] == [NSNull null] ? nil : dict[@"updated_at"];

    [self addChecklistSections:dict[@"checklist_sections"] withChecklist:checklist withContext:context];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [self saveMasterContext];

    return checklist;
}
```

Code for `getUserWithId: withContext:`

```
- (Users *) getUserWithId:(NSString *)user_id withContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *) context
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Users" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(user_id = %@)", user_id];
    [request setPredicate:pred];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *users = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (users == nil || users.count == 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    return users[0];
}
```

Comment: You should post the content of `addChecklist` and `getUserWithId`. Your error is triggered by using two MOC for creating two different entities and then create a relationship between them. So make sure that you are using the same NSManagedObjectContext for both `Checklist` and `Users` entities.

Comment: @danypata I just added the code you requested

Comment: @danypata the User is definitely not nil - I just printed it out

Comment: Consider logging both `[checklist managedObjectContext]` and `[user managedObjectContext]` instead of `context`, just to rule out possibility that `context` is being changed somehow to make it look like you've put things in the correct context when you log them. Also, perhaps review the code to `saveMasterContext` and verify it's not tampering with `context` somehow.

Comment: @CarlVeazey I verified they are the same contexts by printing out the managedObjectContexts as you suggested.

Comment: @workInAFishBowl did you figure out why you are getting this error? I am also getting it in the crash logs for my users and I cannot figure out why. I would love to hear what you found!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see the motivation of making a `mutableCopy` of your fetched users. I think that might be the reason you get the context error. In theory it should just make a copy of the pointers to your objects, but who knows what's happening behind the scenes.

Instead, set the fetch request's `fetchLimit` to `1` and just check if you get exactly one results. Return directly this result, not a copy thereof.

It is also not clear why you are calling a context save method (saveMasterContext) when you anyway pass the context. It would be more logical to call

```
[context save:nil];
```

Also, following Apple's copious sample code you should consider making the context a `@property` of the class rather than passing it around as method arguments.

--

BTW, I really think you should drop the habit of naming your entities in the plural. A checklist is really a checklist, not a checklists.

Also, an id scheme relying on strings is not very efficient. Consider using a numeric equivalent. Also, I find assigning a random checklist id rather risky.

Also, you have a few stray lines in the code such as defining an unused variable for user defaults just before returning from `addChecklist`.